# How to compare signs of two numbers without using < or >?

Tags: python

I need to compare 2 numbers,
if they have the same sign (positive or negative), print "same sign".
If they have a different sign, print "different sign"

The catch is, I need to do it without the use of `<` or `>` (greater than or less than) and only using addition and subtraction of `num1` and `num2`. You can also use 0 (no other numbers).

Here is what it looks like with the <>s:

```
num1 = int(input("enter num1: "))
num2 = int(input("enter num2: "))

if num1 < 0 and num2 < 0:   print("same sign")

if num1 > 0 and num2 > 0:   print("same sign")

if num1 > 0 and num2 < 0:   print("different sign")

if num1 < 0 and num2 > 0:   print("different sign")
```

Comment: StackOverflow's scope is **practical**, answerable problems. For programming puzzles and code golf, there's a separate StackExchange site: [codegolf.se]

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I asked this on code golf and got downvoted then it got put on hold. thanks for the advice. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141020/python-challenge-comparing-signs-of-2-numbers-without-using-or

Comment: Being off-topic there doesn't make it on-topic here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use subtract the number by itself and if the result equal to zero in the two numbers or non equal to zero is the two numbers then it is the same sign, else different sign, here is the code:

```
num1 = int(input("enter num1: "))
num2 = int(input("enter num2: "))

if num1 + 0 - num1 == 0 and num2 + 0 - num2 == 0:  print("same sign") # +

elif num1 + 0 - num1 != 0 and num2 + 0 - num2 != 0:  print("same sign") # -

else: print("different sign")
```

Comment: This isn't runnable Python code and if it were, your first test would always succeed and print "same sign" even if they weren't, `-4 - -4 == 0 and 5 - 5 == 0` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: What @cdlane said, it will always equal "same sign"

Comment: @Dylan Grove I fixed the issue and the logic now should work properly

Comment: Still produces `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when run.  Fixing the `= 0` vs. `== 0 ` issue, it runs but claims that 1 and -1 are the same sign: `if (1 - 1 == 0 and 1 + 1 != 0) and (-1 - -1 == 0 and -1 + -1 != 0): print("same sign")`

Comment: @cdlane see this fix

Comment: I must be missing something as 1 and -1 still print `"same sign"` when I run it.  `if 1 + 0 - 1 == 0 and -1 + 0 - -1 == 0: print("same sign")`

Comment: @cdlane, 1 + (-1) will equal 0 and -1 + (-1) will not equal 0, what is the problem.

Comment: It's not `-1 + (-1)`, it's `-1 - (-1)` -- run your code above with inputs 1 and -1

Comment: How is this accepted? It's simply gives wrong results... What's the point of adding `0`? It does nothing and then your code is just `num1 - num1` which is of course always 0...

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether two numbers `x` and `y` have the same sign by validating the following:

```
same_sign = abs(x) + abs(y) == abs(x + y)
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late here, but this is what I figured out.

```
def sameSign(x, y)
    if (x*y > 0):
        print("same sign")
    else:
        print("different sign")
```

Negative times negative and positive time positive both always give positive. Negative time positive gives negative. If you pass in zero, you always get false, so you could add a check.

Comment: Even the title says *"without using < or >"*...

Comment: I think the question refers to comparing the 2 numbers, if `x = 1` and `y = -1`  `y>x` will be `false` and will remain so if the 2 are the same sign.  This solution has the merit of working in either cases, regardless of the sign.

Answer (score 1):

Well, mb not the prettiest solution, but have a check

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

num1 = 10
num2 = 2

if ((num1 & 0x800000) == (num2 & 0x800000)):
    print('same sign')
else:
    print('different sign')
```

the trick here, that int type in Python takes 24 bits = 3 bytes. Signed types have 1 in the most significant position. 0x800000 = 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000b. If both nums have this bit - same sign, otherwise - different.

Comment: Unfortunetly, this uses other numbers than num1, num2, and 0. I messed up in clarification